# Vue3/Pinia: mutating state crashes Webkit only on Vite prod build

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs3, vite, pinia

I have a pretty straight forward Vue3/Vite project. It works fine with `npm run dev` in FF and Chrome **but** the production build (`npm run build`) with default params crashes Chrome.

The offending part is a async get info action in my Pinia store which iterates over an array to fire XHR Requests and push the result into state variables:

`async getInfo() { Promises.all(someArray.map(i=>axios.get(i)) .then(res=>res.forEach(i=>this._myStateVariable.push(i.data)))`

As long as I simply `console.log` the results, everything is running fine but as soon as I put the result in my state, everything crashes but **only** on Chrome and Safari and **only** if I use the production build from vite.

I don't believe I've got an infinite loop here since it's working fine on FF

So the question is, how do I put the results of those requests into the Pinia store without crashing Chrome?
I also tried building an array first and shoving it into the state at once:
`this._myStateVariable = someArrayFromXhrData;`
`this.$patch(_myStateVariable:someArrayFromXhrData);`

I also tried switching the build target to es2015 but no luck.
Does anyone have an idea how to get to the root of this?

**Solution** Turns out I did have an infinite loop since on of my methods was mutating the state. After updating Vue to the latest version it was actually reported in the Chrome console. I still find it weird that it worked and wasn't reported in FF though but whatever ...

Comment: Hard to say/help you here. Try to comment parts of the code, check recursivity, heavy parts with dynamic pieces of script, your CSS etc.

Comment: @Thomas I have a similar problem. Can you explain me more about your infinite loop? I just can't see any inifinite loop at my side in my code, but have the same problem as you.